# Help me C# code backup/recover & Search contacts on WindowsMobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Hi everyone
I studying about programming on windows mobile. And I build a mini program about "manage contacts" with functions: Add, Edit, Delete, Search and Sort by group. But I don't know how to complete function : search and BackUp/recovery contacts! Can you help me?

---

Description about Search function: I create a **textbox** and **listBox**, when i press any word on textbox, ***Name of contacts containing word*** will ***display on listbox***!
Can you help me?

This is my demo, I convert and repair from example of windows mobile 5.0

This is form main, and picture about main form here : 
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-lMmKCF6-REQ/TcqwNk9kgdI/AAAAAAAAAB4/-Eis3miMHy0/s320/Main.JPG

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook;
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Telephony;

namespace ManagerContacts
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Form1.
    /// </summary>
    public class ContactSelector : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;

        private OutlookSession outlookSession;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox smsText;
        //private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCallWork;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnEdit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnNew;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSendSms;
        private Button bntDel;
        private TextBox textBox1;
        private PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private Button button2;
        private Button bntBackUp;
        private PictureBox pictureBox;
        private Contact   contactToSelect;

        //
        // Constructor
        //
        public ContactSelector()
        {            
            this.outlookSession = new OutlookSession();
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.InitializeListBox();            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function displays a dialog that lets the user pick a contact from a List or
        /// create a new contact. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The function returns the Contact chosen or a new Contact object if the user pressed "New" on the dialog.</returns>
        public Contact Select()
        {     
            this.ShowDialog();
            return this.contactToSelect;

        }


        // Clean up any resources being used.

        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ContactSelector));
            this.btnEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.btnNew = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnSendSms = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.smsText = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.bntDel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.bntBackUp = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.pictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnEdit
            // 
            this.btnEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 70);
            this.btnEdit.Name = "btnEdit";
            this.btnEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 24);
            this.btnEdit.TabIndex = 7;
            this.btnEdit.Text = "Edit Contact";
            this.btnEdit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.EditButton_Click);
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 32);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 198);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // btnNew
            // 
            this.btnNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 40);
            this.btnNew.Name = "btnNew";
            this.btnNew.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 24);
            this.btnNew.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnNew.Text = "Add Contact";
            this.btnNew.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.NewButton_Click);
            // 
            // btnSendSms
            // 
            this.btnSendSms.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(201, 240);
            this.btnSendSms.Name = "btnSendSms";
            this.btnSendSms.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(36, 24);
            this.btnSendSms.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnSendSms.Text = "SMS";
            this.btnSendSms.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SendSmsButton_Click);
            // 
            // smsText
            // 
            this.smsText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 240);
            this.smsText.Name = "smsText";
            this.smsText.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 21);
            this.smsText.TabIndex = 3;
            this.smsText.Text = "Write SMS Text here.";
            // 
            // bntDel
            // 
            this.bntDel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 100);
            this.bntDel.Name = "bntDel";
            this.bntDel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 24);
            this.bntDel.TabIndex = 8;
            this.bntDel.Text = "Del Contact";
            this.bntDel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntDel_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 5);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(188, 21);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 9;
            this.textBox1.Text = "Search";
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 5);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(158, 267);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 24);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 13;
            this.button2.Text = "Exit";
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // bntBackUp
            // 
            this.bntBackUp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 266);
            this.bntBackUp.Name = "bntBackUp";
            this.bntBackUp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(142, 27);
            this.bntBackUp.TabIndex = 15;
            this.bntBackUp.Text = "BackUp And Recovery";
            this.bntBackUp.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bntBackUp_Click);
            // 
            // pictureBox
            // 
            this.pictureBox.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox.Image")));
            this.pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 130);
            this.pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox";
            this.pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 83);
            this.pictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
            // 
            // ContactSelector
            // 
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 296);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.bntBackUp);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.bntDel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.smsText);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSendSms);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnNew);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnEdit);
            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.Name = "ContactSelector";
            this.Text = "Contact Selector";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void InitializeListBox()
        {            

            this.listBox1.DataSource = null; 
            this.listBox1.DataSource = this.outlookSession.Contacts.Items;
            this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "FileAs";
            this.listBox1.ValueMember = "ItemId";
        }

        #endregion


        static void Main() 
        {            
            Application.Run(new ContactSelector());
        }


        private void NewButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {                   
            // Add contact to the contacts folder. 
            // Just do an update once the information has been entered.
            contactToSelect = new Contact();                        
            this.outlookSession.Contacts.Items.Add(contactToSelect);

            // Edit the newly created contact.
            ContactEditor contactDialog = new ContactEditor();
            contactDialog.Edit(ref contactToSelect);    

            this.InitializeListBox();
        }

        private void EditButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (this.listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                contactToSelect = (Contact)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
            } 

            ContactEditor contactDialog = new ContactEditor();
            contactDialog.Edit(ref contactToSelect);
        }


        private void SendSmsButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           try
           {
                contactToSelect = (Contact)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
                if (outlookSession.SmsAccount == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("The account is not initialized");
                MessageBox.Show("Transport:"+outlookSession.SmsAccount.Name);
                SmsMessage s = new SmsMessage(contactToSelect.MobileTelephoneNumber, this.smsText.Text);
                s.Body = this.smsText.Text; //Create some input.
                s.Send();
           }
           catch (NullReferenceException except)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(except.ToString());
           }
        }



        private void bntDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            contactToSelect = (Contact)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
            contactToSelect.Delete();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void bntBackUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm BR = new MainForm();
            BR.Show();
        }

        private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             * contactToSelect = (Contact)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;
            Phone p = new Phone();
            p.Talk(contactToSelect.MobileTelephoneNumber);
             */
        }




    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You should paste pertinent portions of your code. If you remove the file from the location above, this question becomes meaningless. Focus your question on one aspect of your problem...say, *"How do I add records to a Windows Mobile database?"* Supply smippets of code that explain what you have been trying. I, personally, will not download and unzip a .rar file. I will look at code you have pasted into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is very broad, and I agree with IAbstract, I will not download your .rar file.

You may be able to search by having the user enter their query into a textbox and click a button. Then it will compare the textbox string with a dictionary that is created on the application load. This dictionary will contain the name and then data that will let you navigate to the selected contact.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myDict.ContainsKey(textBox1.Text))
        {
            string contact = myDict[textBox1.Text]; //I dont know how you would store
                                                    //the navigation info. Here it is a string
            //
            //Navigate to relevant contact
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
            //return that no contacts were found
            //
        }
```

I didn't compile this code, so If somebody sees that I got something wrong, just comment and I will fix.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'll post my code! Now I complate function backup and retore contacts, but function: search and sort contact by Group i still failed! because I don't know much about C#.Net and windows mobile 5.0!

Comment: Thats how I would do it, but then again I dont work with win mobile. Here are some c# resources [C# Station](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766)